# Word Automation with VB.NET

Tags: vb.net, automation

I'm trying to do a simple application in vb.net:

- Create a new word document
- Loop through an existing folder for existing word documents.
- Insert each word document found in to the newly created document followed by a page break.
- Save the new word document when finished looping through each file.

Here is my existing code. Pretty basic for now.

```vb
Imports System.IO
Imports Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word


Module Module1
    Sub Main()
        Dim folderPath As String = "C:\Temp\Word Mail Merge\" ' Replace with your folder path
        Dim outputDocumentPath As String = "C:\Temp\Word Mail Merge\appended.docx" ' Replace with your desired output path

        ' Create a Word application
        Dim wordApp As New Application()

        ' Create a new document to append other documents
        Dim outputDoc As Document = wordApp.Documents.Add()

        ' Loop through each Word document in the folder
        For Each filePath As String In Directory.GetFiles(folderPath, "*.docx")
            ' Open the document
            Dim inputDoc As Document = wordApp.Documents.Open(filePath)

            ' Copy the contents of the input document to the output document
            inputDoc.Content.Copy()

            ' Add a page break to separate documents
            outputDoc.Content.InsertBreak(WdBreakType.wdPageBreak)

            ' Close the input document
            inputDoc.Close()
        Next

        ' Save the combined document
        outputDoc.SaveAs2(outputDocumentPath)
        outputDoc.Close()

        ' Quit Word application
        wordApp.Quit()

        Console.WriteLine("Documents appended and saved successfully.")
    End Sub
End Module
```

The problem I'm having is on this line:

```vb
' Add a page break to separate documents
outputDoc.Content.InsertBreak(WdBreakType.wdPageBreak)
```

The exception is:

> System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException: 'The object invoked has disconnected from its clients. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80010108 (RPC_E_DISCONNECTED))'

I'm expecting all of the word documents in the specified folder to be inserted in to a new file creating one document that stores each letter.

Comment: You may consider using [DocumentFormat.OpenXml](https://github.com/dotnet/Open-XML-SDK) NuGet package to read the data. When using _DocumentFormat.OpenXml_ you'll find using the [Open XML SDK 2.5 Productivity Tool](https://github.com/dotnet/Open-XML-SDK/releases/tag/v2.5) to be helpful. However, the Productivity Tool hasn't been updated for newer versions of the OpenXml package, so you may consider using version 2.19 of the _DocumentFormat.OpenXml_ package. Also see [DocumentFormat.OpenXml Documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/documentformat.openxml?view=openxml-2.7.2).